# How do I populate only sibling elements (select option) based on value selected from another select option in react.js

Tags: reactjs

I'm coming from jQuery to React.js, I'm finding it very difficult to reference dom elements based on their relationships.

When I select a country in **Row 1** I want only row 1 state option should change.

**Row 1:**

```
<select class="country"></select>
<select class="state"></selct>
```

**Row 2:**

```
<select class="country"></select>
<select class="state"></selct>
```

In jQuery, I can simply do

```
$('.country').change(function(){
    const countryStates=`
     <option>Country State 1</option>
     <option>Country State 2</option>
    `;
    $(this).next().html(countryState);
});
```

How can I do above using React.js?

Answer (score 0):

Use onChange event:

```
const StateSelector = ({contries, states})=>{
  const [countryId, setCountryId] = useState()
  const handleChangeCountry = useCallback((event)=>{
    setCountryId(event.target.value)
  },[])
  return <>
    <select class="country" value={countryId} onChange={handleChangeContry}>
      {coutries.map(c=>(<option key={/*c.id*/} value={/*c.id*/}>{/*c.name*/}</option>))}
    </select>
    <select class="state">
       {states.filter(/*filter by country, e.g. s => s.countryId == countryId*/)
        .map(s=>(<option key={/*s.id*/} value={/*s.id*/}>{/*s.name*/}</option>))}
    </select>
  </>
}
```